# Optimize Swing Program for OS X Yosemite

Tags: java, swing, look-and-feel, osx-yosemite-beta

I just updated to the public beta of OS X Yosemite. When working with Swing, I notice that the components are not optimized. What I mean is that the buttons look like they are from Mavericks (10.9) instead of Yosemite (10.10). If you don't understand what I mean, I can provide screenshots. Is there any property I can change or is it something that Oracle needs to do?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Oracle now manages the UI delegates used by the Apple [Look & Feel](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/lookandfeel/index.html) as part of [OpenJDK](http://openjdk.java.net),

```
com.apple.laf.AquaLookAndFeel
```

You can see the sources [here](http://hg.openjdk.java.net/jdk8/jdk8/jdk/file/687fd7c7986d/src/macosx/classes/com/apple/laf), but you may want to wait for Oracle to incorporate them into a future build.

Comment: Are you saying that they have already updated the code for Yosemite and we're just waiting for a build? Or are you saying "here are the sources so you can fix it yourself"?

Comment: @Trejkaz: I don't know, but recent [screenshots](http://stackoverflow.com/a/27663749/230513) look promising.

Comment: That looks like the old style, actually. Or actually, the buttons look like the old style, but the border on the text field looks new. At least it means it's being worked on.