# Open a JPanel after pressing a button in a JFrame

Tags: java, swing

I know this question has been asked, but I failed to find a solution.

I created a `JFrame` for Login and I want after the button "Cont Nou" is pressed to open a new window with the jpanel for the new account, but do not know how to da the initial frame to disappear and appear the frame with the jpanel.Do you have any idea? thank you!
This is what i did till now:

This is the `JFrame` with the login:

```
public class LogIn extends JFrame implements ActionListener{

    private JLabel labelEmail;
    private JLabel labelParola;
    private JTextField textFieldEmail;
    private JPasswordField textFieldParola;
    private JButton buttonLogin;
    private JButton buttonContNou;
    public LogIn (){
        super();
        this.setSize(400,200);
        this.setTitle("Login");
        this.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        this.setLayout(null);
        this.setResizable(false);
        this.setupComponents();
    }
    private void setupComponents(){

        labelEmail = new JLabel("Email: ");
        labelParola = new JLabel("Parola: ");
        textFieldEmail = new JTextField();
        textFieldParola = new JPasswordField();
        buttonContNou = new JButton("Cont Nou");
        buttonLogin = new JButton("Login");

        labelEmail.setBounds(30,30,50,20);
        labelParola.setBounds(30,70,50,20);
        textFieldEmail.setBounds(100,30,185,20);
        textFieldParola.setBounds(100,70,185,20);
        buttonContNou.setBounds(185,110,100,20);
        buttonLogin.setBounds(100,110,75,20);

        buttonLogin.addActionListener(this);
        buttonContNou.addActionListener(this);

        this.add(labelEmail);
        this.add(labelParola);
        this.add(textFieldEmail);
        this.add(textFieldParola);
        this.add(buttonLogin);
        this.add(buttonContNou);

    }

   public static void main(String[] args){

       LogIn login= new LogIn();
       login.setVisible(true);
   }

   @Override
   public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {

       if(e.getSource().equals(buttonLogin)){
          boolean toateDateleOk =true;
          textFieldEmail.setBackground(Color.WHITE);
          textFieldParola.setBackground(Color.WHITE);
          if(textFieldEmail.getText().length()==0){
              textFieldEmail.setBackground(Color.RED);
              toateDateleOk =false;
          }
          if(textFieldParola.getPassword().length==0){
              textFieldParola.setBackground(Color.RED);
              toateDateleOk =false;
          }
          if(!toateDateleOk)
              return ;
          else 
             System.out.println("Incepe Procesul de logare");
         if(e.getSource().equals(buttonContNou)){
                //this.dispose();
                //dispose();
                //new NewAccountPanel().setVisible(true);   
                //new secondTab().show();
            }   
         }
   }
}
```

Comment: I forgot to put the code for the Jpanel

Comment: Avoid using `null` layouts, pixel perfect layouts are an illusion within modern ui design.  There are too many factors which affect the individual size of components, none of which you can control. Swing was designed to work with layout managers at the core, discarding these will lead to no end of issues and problems that you will spend more and more time trying to rectify

Comment: [How to Use CardLayout](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/layout/card.html)

Comment: Consider [this example](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26517856/java-swing-where-do-actionlisteners-belong-according-to-mvc-pattern/26518274#26518274)

Comment: [The Use of Multiple JFrames, Good/Bad Practice?](http://stackoverflow.com/q/9554636/418556)

Comment: Thank you, I did not know what layout to choose , so I used null.
I'll try to change it now :)

Comment: *"I did not know what layout to choose"*  Few apps. use only one layout.  Instead use [**combinations** of layout managers](http://stackoverflow.com/a/5630271/418556) to get the result required..

Comment: I discovered why the code I wrote did not work ..
I put parenthesis enclosing actions related to the login button in the wrong place.I must have closed parenthesis before checking if the button for create a new account  was pressed, and now the code works.But thank you for the advice, I managed to change the layout and I also learned how to use MVC now.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Let's start with, you should avoid, wherever possible, extending directly from a top level container, like `JFrame`.  This ties you down to a single use component, you couldn't, for example, re-use the login controls in another window (as part of a large component hierarchy) or within an applet context.  You're also not adding any new functionality to the class itself.

You should also limit the number of windows you are push onto your user, as it can become confusing quickly.  Take a look at [The Use of Multiple JFrames, Good/Bad Practice?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/9554636/418556) for more details.

Instead, you should consider using a MVC ([Model-View-Controller](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Model%E2%80%93view%E2%80%93controller)) design to reduce the amount of coupling between classes and exposure of your components to unwarrented/undesirable modifications.

## Contract (view)

Lets start by defining the contracts, this defines what each element in the process can and is expected to do and the information which is passed around

### `View`

This defines the core functionality of each view in your application.  Each view can have a controller (as defined by `C`) and is expected to provide a `JComponent` as the base representation, which is used to physically add the view to the `Container`

```
public interface View<C> {

    public JComponent getView();
    public void setController(C controller);
    public C getController();
    
}
```

### `LoginView`

This defines what information the login view is expected to provide, in this example, we provide the username and password information as well as a means by which the controller can tell the view that the login attempt failed.  This allows the view to reset the view and display an error message if required

```
public interface LoginView extends View<LoginController> {
    
    public String getUserName();
    public char[] getPassword();
    
    public void loginFailed(String errorMessage);
    
}
```

### `LoginController`

This defines the expected actions a controller for the login view can expected to occur, this are called by the view to tell the controller it should do something...

```
public interface LoginController {
    
    public void performLogin(LoginView view);
    public void loginCanceled(LoginView view);
    
}
```

### `ApplicationView`

I've not provided an example of this, but you can imagine that you'd need to provide the details you might like to provide for interested parties to extract details from the view.

## Implementation

### `LoginPane`

This is the basic `LoginView` implementation...

```
public class LoginPane extends JPanel implements LoginView {
    
    private JTextField userName;
    private JPasswordField password;
    private JButton okButton;
    private JButton cancelButton;
    private LoginController controller;

    public LoginPane() {
        setLayout(new GridBagLayout());
        userName = new JTextField(10);
        password = new JPasswordField(10);
        okButton = new JButton("Ok");
        cancelButton = new JButton("Cancel");
        
        GridBagConstraints gbc = new GridBagConstraints();
        gbc.gridx = 0;
        gbc.gridy = 0;
        gbc.insets = new Insets(2, 2, 2, 2);
        gbc.anchor = GridBagConstraints.WEST;
        
        add(new JLabel("User name: "), gbc);
        gbc.gridy++;
        add(new JLabel("Password: "), gbc);

        gbc.gridx = 1;
        gbc.gridy = 0;
        gbc.gridwidth = 2;
        add(userName, gbc);
        gbc.gridy++;
        add(password, gbc);

        gbc.gridwidth = 1;
        gbc.gridy++;
        add(okButton, gbc);
        gbc.gridx++;
        add(cancelButton, gbc);
        
        okButton.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
            @Override
            public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
                getController().performLogin(LoginPane.this);
            }
        });
        
        cancelButton.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
            @Override
            public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
                getController().loginCanceled(LoginPane.this);
            }
        });
    }

    @Override
    public String getUserName() {
        return userName.getText();
    }

    @Override
    public char[] getPassword() {
        return password.getPassword();
    }

    @Override
    public void loginFailed(String errorMessage) {
        JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(this, errorMessage, "Login failed", JOptionPane.ERROR_MESSAGE);
    }

    @Override
    public void setController(LoginController controller) {
        this.controller = controller;
    }

    @Override
    public JComponent getView() {
        return this;
    }

    @Override
    public LoginController getController() {
        return controller;
    }
    
}
```

### `ApplicationPane`

The basic application `View`

```
public class ApplicationPane extends JPanel implements View {

    public ApplicationPane() {
        setLayout(new GridBagLayout());
        add(new JLabel("Welcome to my awesome application"));
    }
    
    @Override
    public JComponent getView() {
        return this;
    }

    @Override
    public void setController(Object controller) {
        // What ever controller you want to use...
    }

    @Override
    public Object getController() {
        throw new UnsupportedOperationException("Not supported yet."); //To change body of generated methods, choose Tools | Templates.
    }
    
}
```

## Putting it all together...

We'll, that's a lot of info, but how do you use it?

```
public class CoreApplicationCPane extends JPanel {

    protected static final String LOGIN_VIEW = "View.login";
    protected static final String APPLICATION_VIEW = "View.application";
    
    private LoginView loginView;
    private ApplicationPane applicationView;
    private CardLayout cardLayout;
    
    public CoreApplicationCPane() {
        
        cardLayout = new CardLayout();
        setLayout(cardLayout);
        
        loginView = new LoginPane();
        applicationView = new ApplicationPane();
        add(loginView.getView(), LOGIN_VIEW);
        add(applicationView.getView(), APPLICATION_VIEW);
        loginView.setController(new LoginController() {

            @Override
            public void performLogin(LoginView view) {
                // Do what ever you need to do...
                String name = view.getUserName();
                char[] password = view.getPassword();
                //...
                
                cardLayout.show(CoreApplicationCPane.this, APPLICATION_VIEW);
            }

            @Override
            public void loginCanceled(LoginView view) {
                SwingUtilities.windowForComponent(CoreApplicationCPane.this).dispose();
            }
        });
        
        cardLayout.show(this, LOGIN_VIEW);
        
    }
    
}
```

This is basically where everything gets plugged together.  The `LoginView` and `ApplicationView`'s are instantiated and added to the main view and the controller's are plugged in.

[image][image]

Take a look at:

- [Laying Out Components Within a Container](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/layout/index.html)
- [How to Use CardLayout](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/layout/card.html)

for more details.

For a more detail example, take a look at [Java and GUI - Where do ActionListeners belong according to MVC pattern?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26517856/java-swing-where-do-actionlisteners-belong-according-to-mvc-pattern/26518274#26518274)

Answer (score 0):

You know how you called

```
setVisible(true);
```

?

Try

```
setVisible(false);
```

Comment: If the open doesn't call `setVisible(true)` on the `Login` instance, it won't display the login frame...

Comment: yes i know that it is set true,but that is why i put dispose(); if the button is pressed..in this way the login window should be closed..and the new account window should be opened

Comment: I meant to use setVisible(false) to remove the original window, after it was used -- setVisible(true) to display it, setVisible(false) to remove it.  I execute setVisible(false) before I used dispose(), myself, but it is likely that is not necessary.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the JFrame's `dispose()` method to close the current JFrame.
Also, you can instantiate a new JFrame and set it visible:

```
JFrame newFrame = new JFrame();
newFrame.setVisible(true);
this.dispose();
```

(*UPDATE*) *NOTICE*: Although I mentioned the *how to do it* (as this was asked), this does **not** mean it is the best approach to follow.
This is considered a bad practice, as having multiple JFrames can be a nightmare for maintainance and is considered user unfriendly. For more information, look [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9554636/the-use-of-multiple-jframes-good-bad-practice).

Comment: See [The Use of Multiple JFrames, Good/Bad Practice?](http://stackoverflow.com/q/9554636/418556)

Comment: Thank you for the comment, I thought to answer the question, without examining if this is a good or bad practice. I updated my answer, including your SO question.