# How to get a javaFX Application instance it's JFrame

Tags: java, javafx

I'm making a login screen for an application, a basic login system, So I have to pass in the JFrame into the login screen's constructor, so whenever that class is done, it can automatically open the JFrame of the actual program.
Thanks

Comment: What's any of this got to do with JavaFX?  Don't pass one frame to another, pass the information you need to share instead.  This is the basic concept of [Model-View-Controller](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Model%E2%80%93view%E2%80%93controller)

Comment: For [example](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26517856/java-swing-where-do-actionlisteners-belong-according-to-mvc-pattern/26518274#26518274) and [example](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/27663306/open-a-jpanel-after-pressing-a-button-in-a-jframe/27663749#27663749)

Comment: I don't understand those advanced programming topics I'm afraid. But what I did get is that I should just send back data from the login pannel...

Comment: The topics aren't that advance, and if you're using either Swing or (especially) JavaFX, then you should at least understand them at a conceptual level, otherwise you will find you life is increasing complicated and confusing